# How do I convert this OpenGL pointer math to Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, glkit

I’m following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9743/how-to-create-a-simple-2d-iphone-game-with-opengl-es-2-0-and-glkit-part-1#comments) about OpenGL / GLKit for iOS but trying to implement it in Swift. It’s going fine until I get to this part:

```
- (void)render { 

// 1
self.effect.texture2d0.name = self.textureInfo.name;
self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = YES;

// 2    
[self.effect prepareToDraw];

// 3
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);

//---------------- This is where things break down...
long offset = (long)&_quad;        
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(TexturedVertex), (void *) (offset + offsetof(TexturedVertex, geometryVertex)));
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(TexturedVertex), (void *) (offset + offsetof(TexturedVertex, textureVertex)));

// 5    
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

}

@end
```

I have a property `self.quad` that’s a Swift struct like this:

```
struct TexturedVertex {
let geometryVertex: CGPoint
let textureVertex: CGPoint
}

struct TexturedQuad {

let bottomLeft: TexturedVertex
let bottomRight: TexturedVertex
let topLeft: TexturedVertex
let topRight: TexturedVertex
}
```

It’s a fairly straightforward structure, but **I don’t know how to pass it to the last argument of `glVertexAttribPointer`**. Any help would be stellar!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Swift, you can use the generic struct `UnsafePointer` to perform pointer arithmetic and casting.  Swift doesn't have `offsetof`, but you can work around that cleanly by taking `UnsafePointer`s of the `geometryVertex` and `textureVertex` elements directly.

The following code compiles in an iOS playground.  I haven't tested it beyond that but I think it'll work:

```
import OpenGLES
import GLKit

struct TexturedVertex {
    var geometryVertex = GLKVector2()
    var textureVertex = GLKVector2()
}

struct TexturedQuad {
    var bl = TexturedVertex()
    var br = TexturedVertex()
    var tl = TexturedVertex()
    var tr = TexturedVertex()
    init() { }
}

var _quad = TexturedQuad()
withUnsafePointer(&_quad.bl.geometryVertex) { (pointer) -> Void in
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLuint(GLKVertexAttrib.Position.rawValue),
        2, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE),
        GLsizei(sizeof(TexturedVertex)), pointer)
}
withUnsafePointer(&_quad.bl.textureVertex) { (pointer) -> Void in
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLuint(GLKVertexAttrib.TexCoord0.rawValue),
        2, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE),
        GLsizei(sizeof(TexturedVertex)), pointer)
}
```

By the way, using `CGPoint` the way you did in your question is dangerous, because `CGFloat` changes size depending on your target (32-bit or 64-bit), but `GL_FLOAT` always means 32-bit.  The tutorial you're following was written before 64-bit iOS came out.

Comment: Excellent! I’ll also add the next problem in the tutorial is most of GLKit is busted in Swift because Swift lacks `union`. This bit of code gets around the problem though https://github.com/programmingthomas/OpenGL.swift

Comment: Also, yeah, `CGPoint` doesn’t work because the floats are too big. You have to use 32 bit `GL_FLOAT`.